# Help in :hover CSS

Tags: html, css

Does :hover in css only works on `<a>` tags? Or it can work on any HTML tags? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It applies to any element, but IE6 and earlier have a bug which only lets it work on links (`<a>` elements with an `href` attribute).

Answer (score 1):

[Quirksmode has the answer!](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

The summary: IE6 only supports `:hover` on links. Everyone else supports them everywhere.